# Why does React Transition Group give a error?

Tags: reactjs, react-transition-group

I decided to try to use React Transition Group. I followed all rulles written in docs. But I get a mistake that sounds so:
React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
If I remove tag CSSTransition everything works fine. But I just want to get acquanted with this library.
Thank you in advance. I use this library the first time and probably somewhere could make a mistake

My code is below:

```
import Modal from './components/modal/Modal';
import {CSSTransition} from 'react-transition-group';

function Application () {

  const [modalIsOpen, setModalOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const openModal = () => {
    setModalOpen(true);
  };

  const closeModal = () => {
    setModalOpen(false);
  };

<div className="wrap">
        <CSSTransition
          in={modalIsOpen}
          timeout={500}
          classNames="modal-overlay"
        >
          <>
            <Modal
              title="Modal Title"
              onClose={closeModal}
              content={
                <p>
                Hello world
                </p>}
            />
          </>
        </CSSTransition>
      </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot return statement for rendering, you should update code to be like this:

```
import Modal from './components/modal/Modal';
import {CSSTransition} from 'react-transition-group';

function Application () {

  const [modalIsOpen, setModalOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const openModal = () => {
    setModalOpen(true);
  };

  const closeModal = () => {
    setModalOpen(false);
  };
  return(
    <div className="wrap">
        <CSSTransition
          in={modalIsOpen}
          timeout={500}
          classNames="modal-overlay"
        >
          <>
            <Modal
              title="Modal Title"
              onClose={closeModal}
              content={
                <p>
                Hello world
                </p>}
            />
          </>
        </CSSTransition>
     </div>
    );
}
```

Also from their documentation I see that they are using refs also https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/css-transition. So you should probably add it too.

Comment: Despite these updates, my code didn't start working :(

Comment: Do you still have error or transition just does not work correctly? Be sure to add correct class to the element ( and different class states in css).